# Widget overlay in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, widget, overlay, flex3

I would like to make an ImageBrowser into my ImageViewer application.
So i thought an Widget overlay is an nice looking!

http://bernetblog.ch/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/widget.png is a nice looking.

but i don't know what is the best way to do such a thing.
How should i start ?
Maybe , a Canvas with alpha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm uncertain what your question is.
Are you trying to decide how to build the widget itself? Or the widget system?

The "desktop" part should probably be a canvas. The Widget itself is probably a canvas with your content in it. (Or perhaps just your content.) Don't forget to implement the dragging functionality. (There's a bit about that here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/adding_drag_and_drop/)